# XML Query and Retrieving Node Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the value of the node from XML. Here is a short sample of the XML

```
  <cpCollection moduleId="cc5005f4-f1ea-433e-b187-8b769170eae4" dataId="0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698978f">
  <group id="Serialize" name="Serialize">
    <property id="Headline">
      <value>One, Two, Three</value>
    </property>
    <property id="Credit">
      <value>0.25</value>
    </property>
  </group>
</cpCollection>
```

Some of my query is below:

```
select TOP 1000 I.Attributes.value('@id', 'nvarchar(32)') as item_name,
       F.X.value('@id', 'nvarchar(32)') as field_id,
       F.X.value('data(.)', 'nvarchar(256)') as field_value,
       F.X.value('Deck[1]','NVarChar(512)') AS Deck,
       F.X.value('Credit[1]', 'Nvarchar(8)')  As Credit 
from cpsys_DataCurrent as T
  cross apply T.Attributes.nodes('/cpCollection/group') as I(attributes)
  cross apply I.attributes.nodes('property') as F(X)
```

I am not getting the value for Headline or Credit. Just NULL values.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. There is no "Deck" in your XML and the only "Credit" is the value of an id for one of the property nodes. What result were you expecting here?

Comment: Corrected the request. Looking for Headline and Credit

Comment: What result are you expecting though? For example, you could extract the "value" node where the property has an id of "Credit" with something like `F.X.value('(.[@id="Credit"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(512)')` but I'm unsure if this is what you're expecting.

Comment: PERFECT. This syntax got the values.
      `F.X.value('(.[@id="Deck"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(512)') AS Deck,
       F.X.value('(.[@id="Credit"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(8)')  As Credit`

Thanks.

Comment: I have a followup question to this if you can help @ZLK. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291522/xml-query-and-retrieving-node-values-using-id

Answer (score 0):

In XPath `/cpCollection/group/property[@id='Credit']` returns

```
<property id="Credit">
  <value>0.25</value>
</property>
```

Hence, try it in this way

```
F.X.value('[@id="Credit"]', 'Nvarchar(8)')  As Credit
```

Answer (score 0):

ZLK's answer worked. 
`F.X.value('(.[@id="Credit"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(8)')  As Credit`

Comment: You should accept your own answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @cpsys_DataCurrent TABLE ( xmltext XML);
    INSERT INTO  @cpsys_DataCurrent (xmltext)
    VALUES 
        ( N'<cpCollection moduleId="cc5005f4-f1ea-433e-b187-8b769170eae4" dataId="0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698978f">
      <group id="Serialize" name="Serialize">
        <property id="Headline">
          <value>One, Two, Three</value>
        </property>
        <property id="Credit">
          <value>0.25</value>
        </property>
      </group>
    </cpCollection>');


    SELECT TOP 1000 
           T.xmltext.value('(cpCollection/@dataId)[1]', 'nvarchar(32)') as item_name,
           T.xmltext.value('(cpCollection/group/@id)[1]', 'nvarchar(32)') as field_id,
           T.xmltext.value('data(cpCollection/group/property)[1]', 'nvarchar(256)') as field_value,
           T.xmltext.value('(cpCollection/group/property[@id="Headline"]/value)[1]','NVarChar(512)') AS Deck,
           T.xmltext.value('(cpCollection/group/property[@id="Credit"]/value)[1]', 'Nvarchar(8)')  As Credit 
    from @cpsys_DataCurrent as T
```

Result:

```
    item_name                           field_id    field_value         Deck                    Credit
    0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698    Serialize   One, Two, Three         One, Two, Three         0.25
```