# XML Query and Retrieving Node Values using Id

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is related to [XML Query and Retrieving Node Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281811/xml-query-and-retrieving-node-value/54282042#54282042)
.

I'm able to view the XML values now and need to limit an update to just those columns. My results continue to insert NULL values. There is data in the XML. I only provided a small set in the prior question, but there are 50 nodes.

My example is below

```
`Update @temptable_all
    SET Headline = F.X.value('(.[@id="Headline"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(512)')
    SET Credits = F.X.value('(.[@id="Credit"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(8)')
    FROM @temptable_all ta
    CROSS APPLY
        cross apply T.Attributes.nodes('/cpCollection/group') as I(attributes)
        cross apply I.attributes.nodes('property') as F(X)
    WHERE ta.ArticleId = T.DataId`
```

More detailed XML Example:

```
`<cpCollection moduleId="cc5005f4-f1ea-433e-b187-8b769170eae4" dataId="0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698978f">
  <group id="Serialize" name="Serialize">
    <property id="Title">
      <value>One</value>
    </property>
    <property id="StartDate">
      <value>1/1/2019</value>
    </property>
    <property id="EndDate">
      <value>12/31/2019</value>
    </property>
    <property id="Headline">
      <value>One, Two, Three</value>
    </property>
    <property id="Credit">
      <value>0.25</value>
    </property>
  </group>
</cpCollection>`
```

Comment: What is the object `T` in your SQL? The only alias prior to that is `ta`. I'm surprised that SQL even runs; I expected an invalid object error.

Comment: Apologies. Updated:
`Update @temptable_all
    SET Headline = F.X.value('(.[@id="Headline"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(512)'),
    Credits = F.X.value('(.[@id="Credit"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(8)')
    FROM @temptable_all ta
    CROSS APPLY
  cpsys_DataCurrent (NOLOCK) AS T
        cross apply T.Attributes.nodes('/cpCollection/group') as I(attributes)
        cross apply I.attributes.nodes('property') as F(X)
    WHERE ta.ArticleId = T.DataId`

Comment: For this, I believe you just want to remove the second cross apply (`I.attributes.nodes('property')`) and instead just update with something like `I.Attributes.value('(property[@id="Credit"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(8)')`

Comment: That does work. However, when reviewing the execution plan, it shows that it does seek on the XML file of 37k rows. It does this for each XML column I want. The query then takes 4-6 seconds. The net return is 756. I think it reviews every node in the XML file. There 51 nodes in the XML.

Comment: If this is something you are going to be querying so frequently that the speed of the execution matters, consider adding a computed column (persisted) to extract the XML value. For example, create a function that returns the "Credit" value and alter your table, adding the function as a persisted computed column.

Comment: Thanks. That is the conclusion we are coming to. Put the frequent XML nodes into columns. Appreciate your help. Using the technic you described above and cross apply, I can get the SP to run under 4 seconds and that's adequate for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @cpsys_DataCurrent TABLE ( xmltext XML);
    INSERT INTO  @cpsys_DataCurrent (xmltext)
    VALUES 
    ( N'<cpCollection moduleId="cc5005f4-f1ea-433e-b187-8b769170eae4" dataId="0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698978f">
      <group id="Serialize" name="Serialize">
        <property id="Title">
          <value>One</value>
        </property>
        <property id="StartDate">
          <value>1/1/2019</value>
        </property>
        <property id="EndDate">
          <value>12/31/2019</value>
        </property>
        <property id="Headline">
          <value>One, Two, Three</value>
        </property>
        <property id="Credit">
          <value>0.25</value>
        </property>
      </group>
    </cpCollection>');

    DECLARE @temptable_all TABLE (ArticleId nvarchar(36), HeadLine nvarchar(512), Credits nvarchar(8));
    INSERT INTO @temptable_all (ArticleId,HeadLine,Credits)
    VALUES 
         ('0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698978f',null,null)
        ,('0000000-000000',N'SomeThing',N'SomeMore');
    --Test selected records 
        SELECT ta.ArticleId,
               T.xmltext.value('(cpCollection/@dataId)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as DataId,
    T.xmltext.value('(/cpCollection/group/property[@id="Headline"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(512)') AS HeadLine, 
    T.xmltext.value('(/cpCollection/group/property[@id="Credit"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(8)') AS Credits
    FROM @temptable_all ta 
    INNER JOIN  @cpsys_DataCurrent  AS T 
            ON ta.ArticleId = T.xmltext.value('(cpCollection/@dataId)[1]','nvarchar(100)');

    --Actual update query
    UPDATE @temptable_all 
        SET Headline = T.xmltext.value('(/cpCollection/group/property[@id="Headline"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(512)') , 
            Credits = T.xmltext.value('(/cpCollection/group/property[@id="Credit"]/value/text())[1]','nvarchar(8)') 
        FROM @temptable_all ta 
        INNER JOIN  @cpsys_DataCurrent  AS T 
            ON ta.ArticleId = T.xmltext.value('(cpCollection/@dataId)[1]','nvarchar(100)');

    --Select after updating
    SELECT ArticleId,HeadLine,Credits FROM @temptable_all;
```

The result from "test selected records":

```
    ArticleId                                   DataId                          HeadLine    Credits
    0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698978f    0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698978f    One, Two, Three 0.25
```

The result from "select after update":

```
    ArticleId                                   HeadLine    Credits
    0a0e2ddf-2a38-4739-9a52-000f9698978f    One, Two, Three 0.25
    0000000-000000  SomeThing   SomeMore
```

Comment: Thanks. The syntax is correct. However, going over 4 million records is very slow. So far the CROSS APPLY query @ZLK provided works the best for a large dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. I still believe that you have plenty more space for improvement. Don't give up.